# check if else condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I have jquery which print the remaining time of quiz to my page. It works fine. Now I want to put condition if else to output of timer_check.php's output. I have put condition if remaining time = 0 then echo timeout else print remaining time. My jquery is in quiz.php page. I want to check if output come from timer_check.php is timeout then All answer should submit to database else print remaining time in tableHolder div. So my question is how to put if else condition for output come from timer_check.php to quiz.php to check submit the quiz or print remaining time?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#tableHolder').load('timer_check.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
    });
}
```

**timer_check.php**

```
session_start();
include("database.php");
$sql = "select * from ctip_test where test_id = '$_SESSION[testid]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $starttime = $row['attemp_time'];
}
$datetime1 = new DateTime($starttime);
$datetime1->add(new DateInterval('P0Y0M0DT2H0M0S'));
$currenttime =date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$datetime2 = new DateTime($currenttime);
$diff = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$check_timeout = (array) $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$hour = $check_timeout['h'];
$minute = $check_timeout['i'];
$second = $check_timeout['s'];
if($hour=="0" && $minute =="0" && $second =="0"){
    echo "time out";
}
else{
  echo($diff->format("%h hours %i minutes and %s seconds are remaining\n"));
}
```

Comment: show your `timer_check.php`

Comment: @Outlooker above is code of timer_check.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the load function you could try using an ajax function.Hope this might give you some idea mate..  :)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $.ajax({
                    url: "timer_check.php",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result == "time out"){
                            $("#myId").submit(); // myId is the id of the form
                        }else{
                            $('#tableHolder').html(result);
                           setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

**FYI**

[ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: what result return? it is not showing remaining time to my page. And I have not any idea about above code.

Comment: result variable returns what is been echoed from your php file.Try putting an `alert(result)` before the `if statement`

Comment: Your condition is wrong if result == "time out" then submit. And other query is every second my jquery call timer_check.php how to implement same?

Comment: I want to call every second this function how to implement this?

Comment: try adding `setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);` after `$('#tableHolder').html(result);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71309/discussion-between-lokesh-and-outlooker).